# Optimal List Comprehension (Filtering Existing List)

Tags: python, list, optimization, micro-optimization

I have a large list (1e8+ entries) in the form `[index:boolean]`. I want to find the indices of the values that are True. ***Performance in this task is of the utmost importance.***

Currently from what I can tell in Python 3.7.2, the optimal way of doing this is using a list comprehension as follows:

```py
return [i for i, j in enumerate(numbers) if j]
```

I have also tried the following (although it seems to simply be the preferred method from earlier versions of Python):

```py
return list(filter(lambda a: a, numbers))
```

The second approach is about 25% slower than the first approach.

Currently, this operation takes about (0.8*x) time, where the actual logic part of my algorithm takes 'x' time. (For example if the logic takes 10 seconds, extracting the positive values from the list takes about 8 second). I had hoped this operation would be much faster.

Comment: `return [i for i, j in enumerate(numbers) if j]` this will create a list and allocate memory containing those huge numbers how is this the most efficient way ?

Comment: You can create a generator expression and iterate through it lazily on demand.

Comment: Your 2 examples are not equivalent, for the comphrension you use `enumerate()` to get the indexes and  with `filter()` you just extract the truthy booleans- which do you want?

Comment: if you have 2 seperat lists, then you have an `itertools.compress` type solution too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Performance in this task is of the utmost importance

Then you should consider using a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
from random import choice
from timeit import Timer

bools = True, False
li = [choice(bools) for _ in range(int(1e8))]
arr = np.array(li)  

print(Timer(lambda: np.nonzero(arr)).repeat(1, 1))
```

Outputs

```
[0.4524359999999916]
```

That's `0.4524359999999916` seconds.

Comment: Note that, if you are not using numpy to store your original list,  much of that speed boost will be offset by the conversion to an np.array.  It will even be worse if you need to convert the result back into a list (as opposed to the np.array that comes out of it).  So, in order to benefit from numpy, you'll have to use it fully.